# How to add shadow for MDCTextField?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mdc-components

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var txtFirstName: MDCTextField!
var txtFirstNameController: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?
override func viewDidLoad() {
txtFirstNameController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: txtFirstName)
}
```

I want to add shadow to the text field but I couldn't find out how, I am using `MaterialComponents`
I have mentioned all the ways that I have tested and their results here:

1st way:

```
class ShadowLayer : MDCTextField{
override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return MDCShadowLayer.self
}

var shadowLayer: MDCShadowLayer {
    return self.layer as! MDCShadowLayer
}

func setDefaultElevation() {
    self.shadowLayer.elevation = .cardResting
}
}
```

2nd way:

```
extension MDCTextField {

func elevate(elevation: Double) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: elevation)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = CGFloat(elevation)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1

}
}
```

[image: choose country -> 1st way, choose city-> 2nd way]

choose country -> 1st way, choose city-> 2nd way

what I want is the pic below:

[image]

Comment: did you try to set txtFirstName.layer.masksToBounds = false;
        txtFirstName.layer.shadowRadius  = 3.0;
        txtFirstName.layer.shadowColor   = UIColor.black.cgColor;
        txtFirstName.layer.shadowOffset  = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 4.0);
        txtFirstName.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;

Comment: yes but it does not work...

Comment: provide more related code. what have you tried? What works? What doesn't? Any picture of expected results? Any picture of current results?

Comment: I add the ways and the pics @GustavoVollbrecht

Comment: im having the same result, but instead im trying to add a white background color

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `self.clipsToBounds = true` **before** setting `self.layer.masksToBounds = false`

Your elevate function should look like this:

```swift
func elevate(elevation: Double) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: elevation)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = CGFloat(elevation)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
}
```

Comment: the result is still the same as the 2nd way. the shadow is still far from the border.

Comment: try applying that into `.textFieldSearchBar` from `MDCTextField `

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. could you explain more?

Comment: The shadow is far from the border because you're setting them in different places, try adding the shadow and the border at `self` on your elevate method.